# Symfony - Log runnables natives queries when database is out

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'am working on a Symfony app that provides a rest web service (simple HTTP Request with JSON).
That service check some rules and inserts few lines in two MySQL table (write only).

For optimize reason, even if Doctrine bundle is available, i use native MySQL Query (with bind params) to insert this lines.

My need is : If for any reason, the database is not available, write "runnables" queries into a log file.

The final purpose is that when database is back, i want to be able to execute directly the file's content on the database.
Note that there is no unique constraint (pk is a generated uuid) and no lock or transaction to handle (simple insert statements).

I write a custom SQLLogger, but when `$connection->insert(...)` is called, the connect fail before logger is called.

So, my question is : There is a way to get the final query (with binded parameters) without database connection ?

Or should i rewrite the mecanism that bind params into query and log it myself when database is not available ?

Best regards,

Julien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the final query with parameters is build by the database, **there is just no way to build the query with PHP and to be garanteed that the query will be the same as the database**.

The only way si to build query without binded parameters, but this is clearly not a good practice.

So, i finally decided to store all the JSON (API request body) in a file if the database is not available.

So when the database is back, instead of replay SQL queries, i can replay the original HTTP query.

Hope this late self-anwser will help someone.

Best regards.